# What is a good way of storing robot paths and access them?

Tags: ros, filter, ros-melodic, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I am writing a controller for a 6DOF robot arm. I am generating paths for the robot to come from the starting point to a desired pose. To do this I do a piecewise polynomial interpolation. Meaning that I first easily interpolate linearly over time between the two points. And then I attach a 6-degree polynomial in the beginning and the end to smoothen the motion. It looks then as follows:

[image: image description]

Now I have the problem, that because of numerical issues (at least I think so) or because of time discretization, I got small jumps between the different polynoms:

[image: image description]

My idea is now to just filter the paths to get rid of these jumps. For this I need to store the path somehow that I can filter it but I don't really have an idea what is a good way of doing this. How are paths saved for example in MoveIt? Do they save discrete or continuous paths?
Is there a way of connecting my polynoms to make it "filterable"?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326079/what-is-a-good-way-of-storing-robot-paths-and-access-them?/) by [dofrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/33370/dofrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
Could you please attach your image directly to the question? You have 11 karma, so you should be able to do this.

**Comment by [dofrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/33370/dofrey/) on 2019-06-18**:
Yes of course. When I posted the question this morning I did not have enough karma yet. Updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fundamentally a joint trajectory is a matrix of points and a matching vector of time offsets (in sections from the start of the trajectory) which give each row of the matrix a point in time. You could write these out to a CSV file fairly easily from a ROS node.

However taking a step back I don't think filtering out these glitches is the best idea, they are probably caused by a bug in your code or error in your maths. There is no reason why you shouldn't be able to produce a perfectly smooth (and tangentially continuous) joint trajectory path. So I would concentrate your efforts there, and hopefully you will not need an additional filtering step.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dofrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/33370/dofrey/) on 2019-06-19**:
Thanks. I really found a bug in my code now that fixed the problem. I gave up after multiple days of debugging but took it up now again.
Thanks anyways for the information about how trajectories are stored usually. My trajectory I store as a function and not as a matrix of points. I think to publish it in RViz I need to convert my functions then to the matrix form.